# How to use "with" in laravel?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I use this package : https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

My laravel eloquent is like this :

```
$query = Product::where('store_id', $id)       
                ->with('store')
                ->get();
```

My product model is like this :

```
public function store()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Store::class, 'store_id', '_id');
}
```

When I execute `dd($query)`, the result is like this :

[image]

Whereas I see in the database, the data exist

I try change to be like this :

```
return $this->belongsTo(Store::class, 'store_id', 'id');
```

It's the same

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please explain your problem in more details.

Comment: Are you really sure, that you have a a Store with that particular id in the stores table? This seems more likely that your database integrity is broken

Answer (score 1):

i think you can solve your problem following this :

```
  $query = Product::with('store')->where('store_id', $id)       
            ->get();
```

And in model :

```
public function store()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Store','store_id', '_id');
}
```

And run this command: 'composer dump-autoload' in your command prompt.

Thanks.....

Comment: what is the use of with() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
public function store()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Store::class, null,  'store_id', '_id');
}
```

Also add

```
protected $primaryKey = 'your_primary_key';
```

to your models.

Hope this helps. :)